# Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

In codeigniter, I have written the following line of code under my methods in the controller:

```
            $dt = new DateTime();
```

In my views page, I've created an h1 tag and placed the following in it:

```
<h1><?php $dt->format('M, d Y'); ?></h1>
```

But I get the following error:

[image]

I would appreciate if anyone can explain this to me in detail.

Comment: need to show more code, what have you passed to the view?

Comment: <?php 

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Times extends CI_Controller
{

 public function main()
 {
  $dt = new DateTime();

  $this->load->view('times_view',$dt);
 }
}

Comment: should read the docs on how to pass data to a view

Comment: I think that you should call $times_view in template instead of calling $dt

Comment: charliefl, can you elobrate more.